# VBA cellextract for multiple xlsx files returning runtime error 9

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

At work, I receive a large number of PDF forms. Entry into the forms occurs in a table within the PDF. Specific entries in the PDF must be entered into an Excel sheet (referred to as the tracker from now on). It's very tedious to add each entry. This method is also prone to error.

I then determined that I could turn each PDF into a .xlsx file, keeping the table format. With cells to reference, I made a VLOOKUP formula to extract the exact info I needed for the tracker. I simply had to copy/paste the table range from the newly created converted .xlsx into my VLOOKUP extractor .xlsx, and the needed info would populate for me to paste into the tracker.

However, using this method, I would still need to convert multiple PDFs to .xlsx, open them one by one, paste the table into my extractor .xlsx, and then copy and paste the new extracted data into the tracker. So, still not quite efficient. I determined that I needed a macro.

The macro I found should loop through .xlsx files in a specified folder, opening them and searching for indicated cells. As you can see in the below macro, the cells aren't in any one range. I must extract values from specific cells.

Next, it should extract the values from the indicated cells and populate them as instructed in the sheet the macro was ran from.

However, I keep getting '**run-time error 9 subscript out of range**' no matter what I do. Debug points to the following line of code as the reason for the error 9: `Set OpenWorksheet = OpenWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)`

I tried replacing `SheetName` in the offending line with `Table1` only to get the same error. Tried `Sheet1` but then get a run-time error 13.

I've been searching the net for a few hours, but I can't quite find a case similar to mine. Any help would be appreciated.

Macro is as follows:

```
Sub ExtractCells()

    ' local wb vars
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MySheet As String
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range
    Dim r4 As Range
    Dim r5 As Range
    Dim r6 As Range
    Dim r7 As Range
    Dim r8 As Range
    Dim r9 As Range
    Dim r10 As Range
    Dim r11 As Range
    Dim r12 As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ' opened wb vars
    Dim OpenWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim OpenWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String

    ' looping params
    Dim Directory As String
    Dim FileSpec As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    ' define looping params
    Directory = "C:\MultiPD Test\Forms\" 'CHANGE THIS
    FileSpec = ".xlsx" 'CHANGE THIS IF NECESSARY
    MyFile = Dir(Directory & "*" & FileSpec)
    SheetName = "Table1" 'CHANGE THIS

    ' set local vars
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    MySheet = "Sheet1" 'CHANGE THIS
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(MySheet)


    ' This is where data will begin to write
    Set r1 = ws.Range("A1")
    Set r2 = ws.Range("B1")
    Set r3 = ws.Range("C1")
    Set r4 = ws.Range("D1")
    Set r5 = ws.Range("E1")
    Set r6 = ws.Range("F1")
    Set r7 = ws.Range("G1")
    Set r8 = ws.Range("H1")
    Set r9 = ws.Range("I1")
    Set r10 = ws.Range("J1")
    Set r11 = ws.Range("K1")
    Set r12 = ws.Range("L1")
    i = 0

    ' If there is one thing you take away from this, it should be the construct below i.e. how to loop through files
    Do While MyFile <> ""

        Set OpenWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\MultiPD Test\Forms\*.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
        Set OpenWorksheet = OpenWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

        ' write data down col
        With OpenWorksheet
            r1.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C4").Value
            r2.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C6").Value
            r3.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C8").Value
            r4.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C10").Value
            r5.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C12").Value
            r6.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C15").Value
            r7.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C16").Value
            r8.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C22").Value
            r9.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C35").Value
            r10.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C36").Value
            r11.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C37").Value
            r12.Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("C38").Value
        End With

        i = i + 1
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are reaching the line that crashes - the line before it (`Set OpenWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\MultiPD Test\Forms\*.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)`) should crash before you get there.

Comment: The error indicates that the worksheet by the name you call it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

- The first line that should throw Run-time error 1004: file "..." could not be found is this:
  `Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\MultiPD Test\Forms\*.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)`
- The next issue is that "Table1" is not a valid sheet name (it seems to be a ListObject name)
- Once all sheets from the .XLSX files were renamed to Sheet1 your code works

---

The version bellow uses an array to reduce repetiton:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractCellsFromMultiFiles()

    Const SRC_COL = 3
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet, wsName As String, srcRows As Variant
    Dim foldr As String, srcFile As String, ext As String

    srcRows = Array(4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 22, 35, 36, 37, 38)

    wsName = "Sheet1" 'Not "Table1", which is probably a ListObject Table name
    Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    foldr = "C:\MultiPD Test\Forms\"
    ext = ".xlsx"

    srcFile = Dir(foldr & "*" & ext)

    Dim srcWB As Workbook, srcWS As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    i = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(srcFile) > 0
        Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=foldr & srcFile, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set srcWS = srcWB.Worksheets(wsName)

        For j = 1 To UBound(srcRows) + 1
            thisWS.Cells(i, j).Value2 = srcWS.Cells(srcRows(j - 1), SRC_COL).Value2
        Next

        i = i + 1
        srcWB.Close False
        srcFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Output:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF    ColG    ColH    ColI    ColJ    ColK    ColL
-----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
S1C4    S1C6    S1C8    S1C10   S1C12   S1C15   S1C16   S1C22   S1C35   S1C36   S1C37   S1C38
S2C4    S2C6    S2C8    S2C10   S2C12   S2C15   S2C16   S2C22   S2C35   S2C36   S2C37   S2C38
S3C4    S3C6    S3C8    S3C10   S3C12   S3C15   S3C16   S3C22   S3C35   S3C36   S3C37   S3C38
```

Comment: Actually it is Table 1. I feel embarrassed but there was a space I needed to add between Table and 1. I'm so sorry...Thank you for the new code though. It looks much cleaner. For some reason my old code wasn't taking cells from multiple files, but instead taking cells from the first file and duplicating them based on how many files were in the target folder. I tried using your code to see if it would be a better substitute. However, when I change `Sheet1` to `Table 1` I get Error 9 again. Recommendations?

Comment: There is a problem with that sheet name (maybe there is a space before or after " Table 1 ". Try renaming the tab to exactly "Sheet1"